# Delegate method not called from Tabbar controller

Tags: ios, swift

I have created a navigation barButton in tabBarController and I want to call delegate method on this button.

```
/// Delegate
protocol DataExportDelegate {
   func generateCSVFile()
}

class TabbarController: UITabBarController {

var exportDelegate: DataExportDelegate?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
 
 ///**barbutton**
let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(
       image: UIImage(named: "icon"),
       style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain,
       target: self, action: #selector(onClick(_:)
       )
    )
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonItem
  }

@objc func onClick(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    exportDelegate?.generateCSVFile()
  }
}

/// ViewController
 class viewController: UIViewController, DataExportDelegate {

var tabbar_Controller: TabbarController = TabbarController()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    tabbar_Controller.exportDelegate = self
}

 func generateCSVFile() {
   print("Delegate called")
 }

}
```

Comment: `var tabbar_Controller: TabbarController = TabbarController()` I don't think that's the same `TabbarController` instance that you are seeing.

Comment: How is `viewController` ralated to `TabbarController`? Also, class names should be uppercased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
var tabbar_Controller: TabbarController = TabbarController()
```

creates a new instance other than the presented 1 ,  so replace

```
tabbar_Controller.exportDelegate = self
```

With

```
(self.tabBarController as! TabbarController).exportDelegate = self
```